# Retrieve the namespace of a class using a trait

Tags: php, reflection

Let's say I have a simple class like this that uses a trait.

```
<?php namespace A\B;

use C\FooTrait;

class D {
    use FooTrait;
}
```

And my trait looks like this.

```
<?php namespace C;

class FooTrait {

    public function getBaseNamespace()
    {
        // code
    }

}
```

My expected behavior would be the following:

```
<?php
$d = new D;
// Shoud be 'A\B';
$d->getBaseNamespace();
```

But so far I haven't been able to do this using the reflection API. Any clues?

Comment: Where is your attempt at using reflection?

Comment: @Flosculus The reflection API provides methods to get the namespace of a class. But I haven't been able to retrieve the name of the class using a trait, from the trait itself.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit more simple than using reflection.
If you are trying to determine it from within the trait method.

You can use:

```
public function getBaseNamespace()
{
    return preg_replace('/(.+)\\\\[^\\\\]+/', '$1', __CLASS__);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `__CLASS__` constant. That's what I was looking for :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php, says it works with traits 5.4+

Comment: Great! That's definitely the way to go. I'm fine using the reflection API over the regex to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

My final implementation is the following.

```
<?php namespace Tools\Namespaces;

use ReflectionClass;

trait NamespaceTrait {

    public function getBaseNamespace()
    {   
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
        return $reflection->getNamespaceName().'\\';
    }
}
```